# AWS VPC charges and cost for multiple subnets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, private, public, amazon-vpc, subnet

I am new to AWS so I am kind of lost here.

I was planning on setting up a system on AWS and I need to hide the DB on a server that does not have access to internet and have another one that will be web server. After I read the documentation I found that can only be done using VPC and subnet, one subnet hidden from internet and the other has access to it.

I haven’t created the AWS account yet but I have seen all tutorials regarding this matter and I know how to do it. Now my question is. How AWS is going to charge me while using the free tier? I know if I have 2 instances one for DB and one for Web server then one of them will be free of charge for 12 months. For the DB server I will not use RDS I will install MySQL myself on the server. So does AWS charge me on any internal data transfers between these 2 servers or just for the web server?
Also, how much this configuration of VPC will cost us per month?

Comment: Curious why you are not using RDS?

Comment: on the long run it will be cheaper for me.